# Excel VBA Formula Inside a String

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-formula

Trying to put a formula inside a string and can't get it working. Can someone help me turn this into a string? I know I need to do ""&"" in places, I just don't know where....

```
Dim form As String
form = =IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sum of Amount]",Pivot!$A$3,"[qAllData].[Year]","[qAllData].[Year].&[2.016E3]","[qAllData].[Month Name]","[qAllData].[Month Name].&["&$B9&"]","[qAllData].[PRODUCT_CODE]","[qAllData].[PRODUCT_CODE].&["&C$3&"]","[qAllData].[Product Name]","[qAllData].[Product Name].&["&C$4&"]")-C8-C7-C6-C5,0)
```

Comment: Do you want it as a string with the references in there, so it'd look like `"=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA(...,Pivot!$A$3,..."` or do you want that `Pivot!$A$3` to actually be the text in that cell?

Comment: What do you want the formula to look like in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Write the desired formula on the sheet itself to make sure it works and post the working formula here with an explanation of which values you want swapped out with variables.  The whole formula must be in quotes with the variables outside those quotes concatenated with `&`.

Comment: start by getting rid of the two consecutive `= =`

Comment: @JohnColeman that's what I meant, that it should be `= "=...`

Comment: That formula I post is a WORKING formula in a current spreadsheet. I use it everyday with no issues. Now I'm trying to automate this process, but need that exact formula in a string variable. As for the double = @ShaiRado that is because I was setting the VAR and the formula itself starts with =.

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, I would like the reference in there. When I get it working, I will use another VAR to replace it by using something like

ref = "C"&ActiveCell.Row

Answer (score 2):

If your formual is verbatim what you have in the spreadsheet but you want to insert it with VBA then just:

```
Dim form As String
form = "=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA(""[Measures].[Sum of Amount]"",Pivot!$A$3,""[qAllData].[Year]"",""[qAllData].[Year].&[2.016E3]"",""[qAllData].[Month Name]"",""[qAllData].[Month Name].&[""&$B9&""]"",""[qAllData].[PRODUCT_CODE]"",""[qAllData].[PRODUCT_CODE].&[""&C$3&""]"",""[qAllData].[Product Name]"",""[qAllData].[Product Name].&[""&C$4&""]"")-C8-C7-C6-C5,0)"
```

This simply replaced each `"` by `""` and wrapped the whole thing in quotes. VBA accepts it as a valid formula, though I am not sure that this is what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a working formula and you just want it in a variable as a `String`, all you need to do is start and end it with double quotes (`"`) and then double all inner quotes (`""`), like so:

```
form = "=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA(""[Measures].[Sum of Amount]"",Pivot!$A$3,""[qAllData].[Year]"",""[qAllData].[Year].&[2.016E3]"",""[qAllData].[Month Name]"",""[qAllData].[Month Name].&[""&$B9&""]"",""[qAllData].[PRODUCT_CODE]"",""[qAllData].[PRODUCT_CODE].&[""&C$3&""]"",""[qAllData].[Product Name]"",""[qAllData].[Product Name].&[""&C$4&""]"")-C8-C7-C6-C5,0)"
```